# Creating filters in play 2.5.X

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am upgrading my service to use Play(Scala) 2.5.X. I am stuck at applying filters to all the responses.
Following are the entries that I added into application.conf

```
play.http.requestHandler = "utils.SimpleHttpRequestHandler"
play.http.filters="utils.CustomFilter"
```

I am authenticating each request which is done in "**utils.SimpleHttpRequestHandler**" and works as expected. However, I am not able to add headers to the response using Filters.
Following is my utils.CustomFilter:

```
@Singleton
class CustomFilter @Inject() (implicit val mat: Materializer) extends DefaultHttpFilters {
  def apply(nextFilter: RequestHeader => Future[Result])(requestHeader: RequestHeader): Future[Result] = {
    nextFilter(requestHeader).map { result =>
      result.withHeaders(
        PRAGMA -> "no-cache",
        CACHE_CONTROL -> "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0",
        EXPIRES -> serverTime
      )
    }
  }
  private def serverTime = {
    val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    val dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z")
    dateFormat.setTimeZone(calendar.getTimeZone)
    dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime())
  }
}
```

Following is my utils.SimpleHttpRequestHandler:

```
@Singleton
class SimpleHttpRequestHandler @Inject() (router: Router) extends HttpRequestHandler {
  def handlerForRequest(request: RequestHeader) = {
    router.routes.lift(request) match {
      case Some(handler) =>
        val response = authenticate(request)
        response match {
          case Ok => (request, handler)
          case Forbidden => (request, controllers.Application.forbidden)
          case Unauthorized => (request, controllers.Application.unauthorized)
          case _ => (request, controllers.Application.badRequest)
        }
      case None => (request, Action(Results.NotFound))
    }
  }
  /* OTHER HELPER METHOD CODE*/
}
```

When I run play-app, I am not getting any warnings or errors, only problem is that filters are not working.
What I am missing or what mistake I am doing?

Answer (score 0):

`CustomFilter` must extend `Filter` but not `DefaultHttpFilters`

Looks like you are not applying the `filter` and also your `application.conf` entry is wrong.

```
package foo

class Filters @Inject() (customFilter: CustomFilter) extends DefaultHttpFilters(customFilter)
```

Your `application.conf` entry should be `play.http.filters=foo.Filters`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.
I changed CstomFilter to:
`code`class CustomFilter @Inject() (implicit val mat: Materializer) extends Filter`code`

Updated application.conf entry
play.http.filters="utils.Filters"

`code`class Filters @Inject() (customFilter: CustomFilter) extends DefaultHttpFilters(customFilter)`code`

But still, headers are not added to response.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.<br/>
I changed CustomFilter to: class CustomFilter @Inject() (implicit val mat: Materializer) extends Filter<br/>
Updated application.conf entry play.http.filters="utils.Filters"<br/>
class Filters @Inject() (customFilter: CustomFilter) extends DefaultHttpFilters(customFilter)<br/>
But still, headers are not added to response.<br/>

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.  
I changed CustomFilter to: class CustomFilter @Inject() (implicit val mat: Materializer) extends Filter  
Updated application.conf entry play.http.filters="utils.Filters"  
class Filters @Inject() (customFilter: CustomFilter) extends DefaultHttpFilters(customFilter)  
But still, headers are not added to response.

Comment: @ShaileshTikhe `CustomFilter` must extend `Filter` not `DefaultHttpFilters `

Comment: @ShaileshTikhe .. your `CustomFilter` must extend `Filter` not `DefaultHttpFilters` ... and everything will work fine

Comment: Yes, `utils.CustomFilter` extends `Filter` and `utils.Filters` extends `DefaultHttpFilters`. But headers are not added to response.

Comment: @ShaileshTikhe here is the screenshot https://s12.postimg.org/vcse3y9vx/Screen_Shot_2016_10_17_at_6_12_32_PM.png

Comment: Can you share your sample implementation with me?
I'll try to compare my implementation with you.
Emaild: shaileshntikhe@gmail.com

Comment: @ShaileshTikhe delete your Handler and handle conf in application.conf and see if it works

Comment: Yes, I tried this yesterday. If I remove handler from application.conf filter starts working.

Comment: I think Filter and RequestHandler doesn't work with each other. If Filter is working then RequestHandler doesn't and if RequestHandler works Filter doesn't. I tried to move both as well as only one class in root package and updated application.conf accordingly. But only one(either Filter or RequestHandler) works for me.

Answer (score 0):

See the source code from https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/http/HttpRequestHandler.scala#L180
and comment:

/**
   * Update the given handler so that when the handler is run any filters will also be run. The
   * default behavior is to wrap all [[play.api.mvc.EssentialAction]]s by calling `filterAction`, but to leave
   * other kinds of handlers unchanged.
   */

```
  protected def filterHandler(request: RequestHeader, handler: Handler): Handler = {
handler match {
  case action: EssentialAction if inContext(request.path) => filterAction(action)
  case handler => handler
}
```

}

The reason your filter is not applied is because you action is not EssentialAction.